# Python - creating directories after button click

Tags: python, linux, glade

I'm a bit new to Python so forgive the ignorance.

I am currently toying with a little app to create directories based on user input. I have made a bash script that does this perfectly but would like put a GUI on it.

So far i have got this function that works:

```
def on_TextEntry_activate(self, widget):
    ParentFolder = widget.get_text()
    os.chdir("/home/user/folder/")
    if not os.path.exists(ParentFolder):
        os.makdirs(ParentFolder), 0755)
    os.chdir(ParentFolder)
    os.makedirs("FolderA", 0755)
    os.makedirs("FolderB", 0755)
    os.makedirs("FolderC", 0755)
    print "Your new folders have been created"
```

So, like i said, this particular function works. What i would like to happen is to have a "create" button that runs this function instead of the text entry box doing it. As i would eventually like to add other text entry box for other things but that's more than likely going to be another post though!!

So if you could then that would be great .. please be gentle with me! :D

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're asking us to write a program for you?

Comment: No, just the function to get a button to apply the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry chaps, i've got the answer to my question now! (see below):

```
def on_createbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    ParentFolder = self.ui.ParentFolder.get_text()
    os.chdir("/home/user/folder/")
    if not os.path.exists(ParentFolder):
        os.makdirs(ParentFolder), 0755)
    os.chdir(ParentFolder)
    os.makedirs("FolderA", 0755)
    os.makedirs("FolderB", 0755)
    os.makedirs("FolderC", 0755)
    print "Your new folders have been created"
```

Just one line is all it takes! << my new mantra

Answer (score -1):

For user interfaces in python, use TKInter to create that button you want. run -pip install TkInter as TK

which version of python are you on?

Comment: I am using Glade for the design and Python 2.7.12

Comment: `pip install Tkinter as TK` won't work for at least a couple reasons. For one, you can't use pip to install tkinter, and two, "as TK" isn't a valid option for pip.